# Create custom Hook to submit form in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, react-hooks

In my project I am using the same logic many times when I submit a form.
Everytime I submit, I display a loader, then remove it and show errors / success.

Is there a way to make a custom hook to avoid it ?

```
const [form, setForm] = useForm(initialState);
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

async function submit() {
  setLoading(true);
  setErrors({});
  const request = await Api.createAccount(form);
  if(request.error) {
    setErrors(request.error.data);
    setLoading(false);
  } else {
    setLoading(false);
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custome hook like this:

```
const useSubmit = ({ initialState }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useForm(initialState);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  async function submit({ onSuccess }) {
    setLoading(true);
    setErrors({});
    const request = await Api.createAccount(form);
    if (request.error) {
      setErrors(request.error.data);
    } else {
      //Do something
      onSuccess && onSuccess()
    }
  }
  return { form, setForm, submit, errors, loading };
};
```

And use it:

```
const { form, setForm, submit, errors, loading } = useSubmit({ initialState });

submit({onSuccess: () => {...your code} })
```

Comment: Thats seems nice but if I use submit, how can I do something specific after success out of custom hook ?